# How to drill down in the data driven unit tests results on Hudson with MSTest

Tags: hudson, mstest, data-driven

Our [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server is powered by [Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29) with [MSTest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSTest).
We use the Hudson MSTest plugin.

Everything works fine, except there is a problem when a data driven unit test fails. The MSTest plugin does not know to drill further down the data rows, like the Visual Studio does when one clicks on a failed data driven unit test.

So, when a data driven unit test fails the error report in Hudson  is absolutely useless - no stack, no reason - nothing.

How do I fix it? I will gladly abandon the MSTest plugin if there is another solution.

Comment: -1 for opening with "Dear sirs".  What about the ladies?

Comment: I beg you pardon. Of course, it should have been "Dear ladies and sirs".

Answer (score 1):

I think this one just needs to be filed as an RFE to the issue tracker, so that the interested party can work on it eventually.